# ¿Cómo creo un fichero de Awk para ejecutarlo?

Tags: awk

Tengo el siguiente código creado

```
awk -F ',' '$4~/finnish/ && $5~/swedish/ {count++} 
            END {printf("%.2f%%\n", 100*count/(NR-1))}' filename.csv
```

Quiero crear ahora un script *.awk para poder después hacer la llamada mediante:
`gawk -f datafile.awk filename.csv` (así debo hacer la llamada y no de otra forma)

Para poder crearlo he seguido los pasos que suelen ser necesarios al crear un *.sh, pero no es correcto lo que estoy haciendo y tampoco veo cómo debo hacerlo

- `touch` para crear
- `nano`para añadir el código indicado previamente
- `chmod +x` para dar permisos

El error mostrado es:

> no se puede abrir el archivo fuente datafile.awk para lectura (No existe el archivo o el directorio)

En cambio, sí que lo puedo ver mediante el comando `ls -li` y además verifico que los permisos son correctos. Indico el resultado obtenido.

*NOTA: el archivo tiene de nombre oficial PAC3_4_a.awk*
Añado imagen con la forma de llamar al script, el error y la comprobación mediante `ls -li`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con Linux (en una máquina virtual) - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Viendo la imagen (no sé si es completa) pareciera que estás buscando el script `PEC3_4_a.awk`, pero este parece que no existe, si existe `PAC3_4_a.awk`

Answer (score 2):

Para convertir un código a fichero de Awk debes tener en cuenta que la orden en sí es lo que va dentro de las comillas simples.

Por tanto, en tu caso el fichero "script.awk" debe contener algo así como:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}

$4~/finnish/ && $5~/swedish/ {count++} 

END {printf("%.2f%%\n", 100*count/(NR-1))}
```

Y luego lo ejecutas con:

```
awk -f script.awk fichero.csv
```

Fíjate cómo `-F','` ha pasado a ser `BEGIN{FS=","}`. Esta es la manera de *moverlo* al script. Si no quieres moverlo así, simplemente mantén el `-F,` en la llamada: `awk -F, -f script.awk fichero.csv`.

Comment: dentro del script que creo, debo añadir ```#!/bin/bash```, cierto? Y algo más? Ejecuto de nuevo con el cambio que me propones pero me da el mismo error

Comment: no, tal cual lo puse yo. El shebang (lo de `#!/bin/bash`) es necesario si quieres poner el archivo como ejecutable. Pero es que no hace falta, Awk ya reconoce los comandos automáticamente como lo que debe ejecutar.

Comment: ok, lo acabo de eliminar pero sigo con el mismo error

Comment: ¿Puedes actualizar tu pregunta dando el resultado de `ls -l` de tu directorio, además de indicar tu sistema operativo?

Comment: hecho. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Imagen añadida también con la lista de permisos

Comment: gracias! ¿Puedes poner también salida (en texto, mejor) de cómo lo ejecutas exactamente?

Comment: actualizado! muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: faltaría más, hombre :) Es raro, parece como que se haya creado el fichero pero con un nombre diferente. ¿Has probado a utilizar el tabulador para intentar completar el nombre del archivo? Haz `gawk -f P<tab>` y así te completará. También puedes recrearlo diciendo `fichero="loquesea.awk"; touch "$fichero"; nano "$fichero"; gawk -f "$fichero" f.csv`. Así estarás siempre operando sobre el mismo nombre de archivo, sin que se cuele ningún carácter raro

Comment: pues nada, sigue sin funcionar. No sé si borrar el *.awk, y rehacer todos los pasos que indico - ```touch``` - ```nano``` - ```chmod +x``` y ver si así funciona

Comment: Prueba a ver, la verdad es que me resulta extraño. Con los pasos que di en mi anterior comentario te debería funcionar.