# ¿Cómo uso Awk para actualizar un fichero poniendo en un campo el valor de la media?

Tags: awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un script de awk hecho: `c_awk.awk` y quiero que la invocación sea de la forma `c_awk.awk <file>`.

Actualmente hago la llamada al fichero desde el propio script.

Este es mi script:

```
#calcular la media y guardar en variable 'var'
var=$(awk -F, '$7{sum+=$7; elementos++} END{print sum/elementos}' file)

#asignar valor de la media
while IFS="," 
read v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 v10 v11 v12 v13; 
do if [ -z "$v6" ]; 
then echo "$v1,$v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11, $var,$v13"; 
else echo "$v1, $v2,$v3,$v4,$v5,$v6,$v7,$v8,$v9,$v10,$v11,$v12,$v13"; 
fi;
done < file
```

El ejecutar el programa se queda atascado.

¿Cómo puedo eliminar del script los `file` para añadirlo en la invocación?

Gracias.

Comment: el script tiene código de Bash, no de Awk. Es decir, la sintaxis es propia de Bash y no de Awk. Para ejecutar un archivo fíjate en la sintaxis descrita en [¿Cómo creo un fichero de Awk para ejecutarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/496279/83)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', claro, aquí me surge la duda entonces de cómo buscar el hueco libre en la columna 6? ```BEGIN {FS='","}  read v1...v13; do if [-z "$v6"] ...```?

Comment: Es que lo que pones es una mezcla de código Awk y Bash, que no va a funcionar. O bien usas todo Awk, o bien usas Bash con llamadas a Awk con `variable=$(comando)`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', claro, pero lo que quiero es usar awk. ```BEGIN {FS=..``` es ```awk```, correcto? ahora me queda el cuerpo y eso era lo que te preguntaba. Gracias!

Comment: He copiado el script en un fichero `sc.sh` y he creado un ejemplo en `file`. Ejecutando `bash sc.sh` me ha funcionado bien, haciendo el cambio correctamente. ¿Cómo lo ejecutas tú?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', pero claro, yo quiero que sea un ```awk```, no un ```bash```. Tengo que cambiar la estructura para que funcione y por eso te preguntaba si ```BEGIN {FS=..``` como en el link que me sugerías era correcto.

Comment: Vale, entonces todo el `while` y demás debe hacerse con Awk. Tipo `!$6 {$6="hola"}`

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', claro, pero eso es lo que no sé cómo hacer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes leer el fichero dos veces: una primera para calcular la media y la segunda para poner la media allí donde no hay valor:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==FNR && $7{sum+=$7; elementos++; next}
     !$7{$7=media}
     {print}
     ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}' fichero fichero
```

La primera parte es la descrita en [awk para calcular edad media](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/502265/83), con el añadido de usar `FNR==NR` para determinar cuándo se está leyendo el fichero por primera vez. Más info en [Idiomatic Awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). Con `ENDFILE{media=sum/elementos}` le decimos que guarde la media en una variable para el uso en la siguiente iteración.

Con `!$7{$7=media}` asigna el valor de la media en aquellos campos número 7 en el que no esté. Luego con `{print}` imprime esa línea.

Comment: y cómo puedo hacer la llamada ahora mediante ```c_awk.awk <file>``` Debería indicarlo 2 veces?

Comment: @IñigoCatalánEchave sí.